# Retirar posições de array que tenham o nome em comum

Tags: php, array

Quero tirar determinadas posições do meu *array* que tenham o nome de posições em comum, e jogar para outro *array*.

EX:

```
array
  'id' => '147' 
  'nome' =>'João' 
  'email' => 'joao@teste.com' 
  'data_nascimento' => '05/01/1987' 
  'numero_1' => '1' 
  'rua_1' => 'rua 1' 
  'numero_2' => '2' 
  'rua_2' => 'rua 2'
  'submit' => 'Salvar'
```

Resultado desejado em um *array*

```
array
  'numero_1' => '1' 
  'numero_2' => '2'
```

Ou algo do gênero

Comment: Mas qual o denominador comum? `numero_1` e `numero_2` são duas coisas diferentes. Ou pretendes `numero_X` ?

Comment: Como assim "que tenham o nome de posições em comum"? Se está falando do nome da chave - o que vem antes do `=>` - não vai existir duas chaves com o mesmo nome em uma array.

Comment: Qual o motivo de "rua_1" e "rua_2" não terem seguido o mesmo critério?

Comment: Não seguiu o mesmo padrão porque vou pegar esse array e fazer o foreach tanto em rua quanto em numero, ou seja onde existir rua vai existir numero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Com o teu código atual, para o objetivo enunciado, podes fazer assim:

```php
$arr = array(
  'id'              => '147',
  'nome'            =>'João',
  'email'           => 'joao@teste.com',
  'data_nascimento' => '05/01/1987',
  'numero_1'        => '1',
  'rua_1'           => 'rua 1', 
  'numero_2'        => '2',
  'rua_2'           => 'rua 2',
  'submit'          => 'Salvar' 
);

$newArr = array();

foreach ($arr as $k => $v)                    // por cada entrada na matriz
    if (strpos($k, "numero_") === 0)          // se começar por "numero_"
        $newArr[$k] = $v;                     // envia para a nova matriz
```

Cujo resultado será:

```php
array(2) {
  ["numero_1"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["numero_2"]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

Ver exemplo no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/zEe5My).

Answer (score 5):

Me pareceu que a intenção é detectar qualquer duplicidade no nome antes do sublinhado (*underscore*) e não só o "numero". E exemplo não bate com a descrição da pergunta.

Então cheguei neste código:

```
$arr = array(
  'id'              => '147',
  'nome'            =>'João',
  'email'           => 'joao@teste.com',
  'data_nascimento' => '05/01/1987',
  'numero_1'        => '1',
  'rua_1'           => 'rua 1', 
  'numero_2'        => '2',
  'rua_2'           => 'rua 2',
  'submit'          => 'Salvar' 
);
$newArr = array();
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    $partes = explode("_", $k);
    if (count($partes) > 1) {
        $repetido = 0;
        foreach ($arr as $k2 => $v2) {
            if (strpos($k2, $partes[0]."_") === 0) {
                $repetido++;
            }
        }
        if ($repetido > 1)
            $newArr[$k] = $v;
    }
}
var_dump($newArr);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/3hDrh9). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/axhnrkjy-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Array/Repeating.php).

Acho que dá para otimizar alguma coisa mas a base é esta.

Resultado:

```
array(4) {
  ["numero_1"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["rua_1"]=>
  string(5) "rua 1"
  ["numero_2"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["rua_2"]=>
  string(5) "rua 2"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Se eu entendi corretamente o objetivo é transferir do array de entrada todos os elementos que possuam um mesmo prefixo caracterizado por uma expressão seguida de um *underscore*.

Sendo assim, proponho o esquema abaixo:

```
$filtered = array();

array_walk(

    $arr,

    function( $current, $offset ) use( $arr, &$filtered ) {

         preg_match( '/(\w+_\d+)/', $offset, $matches );

        if( count( $matches ) > 0 && array_key_exists( $matches[ 1 ], $arr ) ) {

            $filtered[ $matches[ 1 ] ] = $current;
        }
    }
);
```

Usando o array de entrada com o mesmo nome que tem hoje (**$arr**) a matriz resultante **$filtered** terá os seguintes valores:

```
array(
  'numero_1' => '1',
  'rua_1' => 'rua 1',
  'numero_2' => '2',
  'rua_2' => 'rua 2'
)
```

Sua segunda pergunta pode ser respondida simplesmente por computar a diferença entre os dois arrays, original e filtrado:

```
$diff = array_diff_assoc( $arr, $filtered );
```

A matriz **$diff** tem os seguintes valores:

```
array(
  'id' => '147',
  'nome' => 'João',
  'email' => 'joao@teste.com',
  'data_nascimento' => '05/01/1987',
  'submit' => 'Salvar'
)
```

Essa abordagem tem como vantagens:

- Não depender de uma expressão fixa, ou seja, contanto que todas as similaridades sigam o mesmo formato *prefixo_numero*, ela vai funcionar na matriz inteira.
- É rápida, porque dispensa cálculos, condições complexas e loops aninhados. Então mesmo que array grandes sejam bastante ruins para sua Aplicação, ese procedimento não vai ser o seu gargalo.

Answer (score 2):

Minha contribuição, misturando um pouco das respostas já dadas:

```
$arr = array(
  'id'              => '147',
  'nome'            =>'João',
  'email'           => 'joao@teste.com',
  'data_nascimento' => '05/01/1987',
  'numero_1'        => '1',
  'rua_1'           => 'rua 1', 
  'numero_2'        => '2',
  'rua_2'           => 'rua 2',
  'submit'          => 'Salvar' 
);

$padrao = "/[\w]+\_[\d]+/i";
$chaves = array_keys($arr);

foreach ($arr as $chaveAtual => $valor) {
    preg_match($padrao, $chaveAtual, $encontrados);
    $padraoEncontrado = count($encontrados);
    $padraoSeRepete = (int) preg_grep($padrao,$chaves);
    if ((!$padraoEncontrado) || (!$padraoSeRepete)) {
        unset($arr[$chaveAtual]);
    }
}

var_dump($arr);

/*
Resultado:
array(4) {  
  ["numero_1"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["rua_1"]=>
  string(5) "rua 1"
  ["numero_2"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["rua_2"]=>
  string(5) "rua 2"
}
*/
```