# Warning: array_filter() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given

Tags: php, warnings

Tenho o seguinte código que foi retirado do exemplo #3 presente na documentação do PHP para a função [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4);

var_dump(array_filter($arr, function($k) {
    return $k == 'b';
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));
```

Curiosamente, ao testar este código para dar como resposta [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40557/223), obtive o seguinte erro:

> Warning:
> array_filter() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given in /caminho/para/ficheiro.php on line X

Ver no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/YmBCIX).

Mas na documentação, a função está descrita como capaz de aceitar 3 parâmetros:

```
array array_filter ( array $array [, callable $callback [, int $flag = 0 ]] )
```

O terceiro parâmetro é exatamente o motivo pelo qual estava a recorrer a esta função para solucionar o problema.

## Pergunta

O que se está a passar para não poder fazer uso dos três parâmetros?

---

<sup>**Versão do PHP:** 5.3.22 | **Host:** Linux | **API do Servidor:** CGI/FastCGI</sup>

Comment: já me deparei com esse problema uma vez e não encontrei solução

Comment: Lendo a documentação, parece ser problema de versão. Adicionei como resposta ali embaixo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Da [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) da função `array_filter`:

> 5.6.0 Added optional flag parameter and constants ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY and ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH

Sua versão do PHP não tem suporte ao terceiro argumento da *flag*.

Comment: Hmm... Ok, vi agora essa nota. Só a partir da versão **5.6.0** é que temos o terceiro parâmetro. Falta de atenção da minha parte, não tinha lido esse bloco. Obrigado.

Comment: sem problemas ;)